# Split XML to multiple XML files using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml

I am trying to split an XML to multiple XML files using Python. I found the code which only splits the first instance of topic. I tried using `findall` instead of `find`, but it doesn't seem to work. I am new to Python and yet to learn the syntax well. I am using Python 3.

My XML file is of this pattern:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<dita>
<topic id = "topic1">
   <title>ABC</title>
   <body>
    <p>This is topic1.</p>
    </body>
 </topic>
<topic id = "topic2">
 <title>Test / xyz</title>
<section> <title>Section title</title>
<p>This is topic 2. </p>
</section>
</topic>
</dita>
```

Output that I need:

Script must find `<topic>` tag and split content into separate XML.

```xml
ABC.xml
Test.xml

ABC.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<topic id = topic1>
   <title>ABC</title>
   <body>
    <p>This is topic1.</p>
 </topic>

Test.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<topic id = topic2>
 <title>Test</title>
<section> <title>Section title</title>
<p>This is topic 2. </p>
</section>
</topic>
```

My code:

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.iterparse('file.xml', events=('end', ))
index = 0
for event, elem in tree:
    if elem.tag == 'topic':
        index += 1
        title = elem.find('title').text
        filename = format(title + ".xml")
        with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(b"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n")
            f.write(ET.tostring(elem))
```

Comment: Where is your code that didnt work? what error do you get? what issues have you faced?

Comment: Only the first xml got created - ABC.xml. Then, I got the error - FileNotFoundError: No such file or directory: 'Test.xml'

Comment: Can you give a minimum reproducable example, when i use your xml example and the code you have given it gives `xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 3, column 15` as the xml you have proveded is not wellformed valid xml

Comment: The code is added on this page, please look under Code - block. Thanks.

Comment: I got to know what the problem was - there was a backslash in the title element which wasn't being parsed. The title was Test/ xyz. The code added above works perfectly fine without issues.

Comment: This is a good example of why you should always put accurate data. Your original xml data didnt have a title with a slash in it. Nor was it even valid xml. Always give a minimal reproduable example of your data and code.